# How do I point at our new SVN repository with an SVN Client like TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, trac, bitnami

We are migrating from an older Bitnami Trac Stack on a Linux server in a Virtual Box VM to a new Windows native Bitnami Trac Stack on the same server.  I've got both our repositories hotcopied, synched, upgraded and configured, etc. on the new server instance.  By that I mean I can view both SVN source and Trac tickets migrated from the old instance on the new in a browser.

However, I can't view the repositories from a client like TortoiseSVN because I don't know how to reference it.  I'm using the default Apache for a webserver on Trac 1.0.5 (just used the downloaded Windows installed from Bitnami).  I've configured Apache's httpd.conf to:

`Listen 192.168.1.21:8001`

&

`ServerName sbeut01:8001`

And Subversion is on port 3691 (don't know if this is important or not, but since both Apache & SVN ports are non-standard, I wanted to mention them).

If I point TortoiseSVN at //sbeut01:8001/trac/Production_Engineering, it tells me that:

*//sbeut01:8001/trac/Production_Engineering is not a working copy*

**which actually sounds hopeful, maybe I just need to figure out how to turn it into a working copy?**

The link in Trac to view source is:

```
http://sbeut01:8001/trac/Production_Engineering/browser
```

If I put that in TortoiseSVN (minus the /browser bit) it complains about an unexpected http: in the URL.  So, I tried replacing it with:

`svn://sbeut01:8001/trac/Production_Engineering`

Which just sends TortoiseSVN off into la-la land and you have to use Task Manager to kill it.

***How do I figure out where to point external SVN clients to view our repositories?***

Answer (score 0):

You must add another webserver `<Location>` in your /bitnami-trac/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file mapping your SVN server path to the network as URL:

```
<Location /svn/YourRepo1>
DAV svn
SVNPath /where/your/repo/is/on/disk
AuthName "SVN YourRepo1"
AuthBasicProvider ...???...
...???...
AuthType basic
Require valid-user
AuthzSVNAccessFile "/path/to/repoAccess.conf"
</Location>
```

You must decide which authentication you use, maybe LDAP or SSPI or something. Search the web for appropriate Apache configuration options.

This way the Apache webserver maps an SVN URL you can use with your SVN client application like Tortoise. Trac works in parallel and is a different thing hosted by your webserver. Trac accesses SVN in its own way, see /bitnami-trac/properties.ini. If `//sbeut01:8001/trac/Production_Engineering` is your Trac URL, `//sbeut01:8001/svn/YourRepo1` may be your URL for the SVN client applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Neither the original httpd.conf file on the Linux VM or the new one on Windows has a <Location>...</Location> tag?  The Apache2 instance on the old server somehow serves the repository as:`svn.seabird.com`, but I haven't been able to figure out how yet.  I've looked for that string, the server name and it's IP address in various configuration files with no luck.  Your last suggestion results in a _is not a working copy_ error message in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: httpd.conf should include something like /bitnami-trac/apps/trac/conf/trac.conf which contains the Locations for the Trac URLs. Please, check!